# Route53 isn't connecting domain name to ELB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53

I'm in an AWS certification course where they don't respond to student questions. In the lecture we create an EC2 instance, then create an ELB and create a Hosted Zone for a domain name I purchased through AWS. This worked once, but now it's not working. The domain name I have registered doesn't resolve, but the ELB DNS domain name pulls up the web server as does the IP address.

What am I missing?

Comment: How long did you wait after setting up the domain name? It takes a while for DNS records to propagate.

Comment: I thought that might be the issue, so I waited half a day and still nothing.

Comment: You need to provide more info then. What type of DNS record did you create? Is it an apex domain name or a subdomain? What are the results of  `dig <domain-name>` where <domain-name> is the domain name you are pointing at the ELB.

Comment: It's an apex domain, using the Alias function in Route 53. I'm not running Linux so I can't run dig but using nslookup in Windows yields "Server unknown".

Comment: It sounds like you don't have the name servers for your domain configured properly. Go here https://www.misk.com/tools/#dns and test your domain name. If it doesn't come back with the list of name servers Route53 told you to use then you need to look into your domain configuration. Did you buy the domain on AWS or somewhere else?

Comment: If you deleted your hosted zone and then put it back, [there is another necessary step that many people seem to overlook](https://serverfault.com/a/838396/153161).

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Please list this as an answer so I can give you an answer credit. That link provided EXACTLY what I needed. I had my solution in 5 minutes (and I had been working on this for THREE days!). Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

This answer actually came from "Michael - sqlbot" listed above but he never set it as an answer. I'm putting it here just so this question is answered, but he provided the solution.

https://serverfault.com/a/838396/153161